# Behat container keeps exiting

Tags: docker, docker-compose, behat

I'm using the following code to create a Behat docker container:

```
version: '3'
services:
  behat:
    container_name: behat.test
    image: docksal/behat
#    command: tail -F anything
#    tty: true
#    ports:
#      - 4444:4444
#    restart: always
```

But I'm experiencing a persistent problem with the container continually exiting with a code 1 as a result I can't interact with the container.
All the commented out portions of the code are what I have tried to resolve the issue.

Here is the output for the Behat container when I run `docker-compose up -d --build`:

```
d8c515771e4d        docksal/behat                              "behat"                  6 seconds ago       Exited (1) 5 seconds ago                            behat.test
```

### Update

I found Behat was reporting the following error :

```
 `FeatureContext` context class not found and can not be used.
```

Comment: Are you building the image yourself, or running a prebuilt image off of Docker Hub?  If it's your own image, can you edit the question to include its Dockerfile?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: (Aside: your posting is still rather chatty, and features something of a nagging, needy tone. Please again try to stick to technical writing, to reduce the amount of work required from volunteer editors).

Comment: @DavidMaze: I am using the prebuilt  docksal/behat image

Answer (score 1):

> `FeatureContext` context class not found and can not be used.

This means `behat` fails to find `features` which needed, you could use `behat --init` to init a one.

```
$ docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/src docksal/behat --init
+d features - place your *.feature files here
+d features/bootstrap - place your context classes here
+f features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php - place your definitions, transformations and hooks here
```

Then in your host, there will be a `features` folder, then run the command again see it's ok now:

```
$ docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/src docksal/behat
No scenarios
No steps
0m0.00s (7.73Mb)
```

For `docker-compose`, it's same, you need to assure there is `features` mount to the container. You could reference [official folder structure](https://github.com/docksal/behat/tree/develop/example) to have your design, a workable step as next:

1. In current folder:

   ```
   docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/src docksal/behat --init
   ```
2. Write a `docker-compose.yaml` like next:

   ```
   version: "2.1"

   services:
     # Behat
     behat:
       hostname: behat
       image: ${BEHAT_IMAGE:-docksal/behat}
       volumes:
         - .:/src
       # Run a built-in web server for access to HTML reports
       ports:
         - 8000:8000
       entrypoint: "php -S 0.0.0.0:8000"
   ```
3. `docker-compose up -d`

   ```
   $ docker ps
   CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             
   STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
   55f506afe31a        docksal/behat       "php -S 0.0.0.0:8000"    29 seconds ago      Up 25 seconds       0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp    2020121502_behat_1
   $ docker logs 2020121502_behat_1
   PHP 7.3.25 Development Server started at Tue Dec 15 05:39:00 2020
   ```

Comment: I am getting: 
```
PHP 7.3.25 Development Server started at Sun Mar 24 10:49:02 2024
[Sun Mar 24 10:49:34 2024] 192.168.16.1:59324 [404]: / - No such file or directory
[Sun Mar 24 10:49:34 2024] 192.168.16.1:59326 [404]: /favicon.ico - No such file or directory
[Sun Mar 24 10:50:16 2024] 192.168.16.1:55126 [404]: / - No such file or directory
[Sun Mar 24 10:50:25 2024] 192.168.16.1:48596 [404]: / - No such file or directory
PHP 7.3.25 Development Server started at Sun Mar 24 10:52:15 2024
[Sun Mar 24 10:52:47 2024] 192.168.16.1:59922 [404]: /src - No such file or directory
```